# tomcat 8.0 server pointing to old git location

Tags: java, git, maven, tomcat8

I am facing this issue after getting the code from GIT to a new folder.
Except the server, all other project components are pointing to new GIT branch. When I run the solution on server, it fails with 404 error.

Tried Maven clean, refresh, start/stop tomcat server, deleting/adding back tomcat but still the problem persists.

Attached the screengrab https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nUoG.png

Thank you.

Comment: You need to add much more detail.

Comment: Do you expect people at SO to have supernatural powers? Without any details provides, your question makes no sense at all